# lxml: xpath search within subelement

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm wirting a script to scrape a webpage. My (debug) code is as follows (saved a local copy for faster testing):

```
doc = html.parse("C:\debug.html")
links = doc.xpath("//div[@class='download_item']")
print(links[0].xpath("//div[@class='download_title']"))
print(doc.xpath("//div[@class='download_title']")
```

For me unexpected, both printouts yield the same result (The one I would expect to search the whole document.)
I verified that the "links" list contains the desired results. Now I want to search each element of links for the "download_title" class. There should be only one result per element.
However it seems that the whole document is scanned.
My question is why xpath does not search the element indicated (links[0]) but the whole document (doc) and how to search only the subelement links[0]

Comment: Read up on [XPath - Quick Guide](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_quick_guide.htm) section **XPath - Expression**.

Comment: With trial and error I found that `links[0].xpath(".//div[@class='download_title']")` does what I want. I still don't understand why the dot before the // is neccessary. The guide says " // Selection starts from the current node that match the selection". So why does the search does not start in links[0] but in doc.

Comment: ***"guide says " // Selection starts from the current node that match the selection"***:  Confusing, I agree, the differents to `'.'` is ***"...that match the selection"***. Whatever that means.

Comment: It is described more clearly in the XPath 1.0 recommendation (https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev). `//para` selects all the `para` descendants of the document root and thus selects all `para` elements in the same document as the context node. `.//para` selects the `para` element descendants of the context node.

Comment: Thank you @mzjn. Very helpful link that I bookmarked now.